# Odoo13 : Stripe Payment Gateway Server error - We are not able to redirect you to the payment form. id

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments, odoo-13

I've installed the Odoo-13 application on my server. In which I'm getting **Server error - We are not able to redirect you to the payment form. id** error while doing payment using Stripe(Sandbox mode).

I have attached a screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am having the same problem did you find solution

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set an account or business name at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account.

Comment: Would this be better left as a Comment, than an "Answer"?

Comment: @SherylHohman I think their user score is too low to write comments

Comment: @rhavelka: this does not change my comment. It is also why I did not flag for deletion: just in case it *is* the ("OMG, duh!") solution, I didn't necessarily want to *immediately* delete one of the only "answers" suggested, especially since this Q is not my expertise. Useful comments-as-answers are routinely deleted despite a low rep excuse. NOTE: It *IS* useful for the contributor to know that, even if not removed, distinguishing between answers and comments needs to be made on future contributions, *especially* once rep *has* been achieved. I considered it an heads-up case. Learning SO.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like there is a coding error in the definition of the promise or of the handlers.

In Odoo13 they have introduced the **guardedCatch** with rejected reason is an error.

More you can Trace on the **payment_form.js** file and also have some idea from this 
[click here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/javascript_cheatsheet.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the right journal, when I create my invoice by code I do

```
journal_id = request.env['account.journal'].search([
  ('type','=','sale'),
  ('company_id','=', company[0].id)]
)[0]
                    
request.env['account.move'].create({
   ...
   'journal_id': journal_id.id,
   ...
```